# How to remove all duplicates from a list

Tags: java, list, duplicates

I am trying to remove all duplicate elements from a list, without using set and elements should remain in order.

My code is not working properly, I assume there is something with for loops as it is not going all around.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

**Code:**

```
public class DuplicatesCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Enter elements:");
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          String input = scan.nextLine();
          List<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(input.split(",")));
          List<String> elements2 = new ArrayList<String>();
          elements2 = elements;

         for(int i = 0; I < elements.size() - 1 ; i++ ) {
             for(int j = i + 1; j < elements.size(); j++) {             
                if(elements.get(i).equals(elements.get(j))) {                           
                    elements2.remove(j);                     
                }
             }
         }
         System.out.println(elements2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t interate with index. Because once you delete an element the elements.size() decreases by 1. So j++ will skip an element. Hence iterate using foreach or increment j only if not removed. If removed your j points to next element only. Because when a element is removed from list, remaining elements shift left.

Hope that helps. I can post full solution if you need.

Comment: Thank you very much! So probably as I checked on google, as this is new for me, it should be something like:
 
    for(String i : elements ) {
     
     for(String j : elements) {
    
      
     if(i.equals(j) {    
      
       
      elements2.remove(elements.indexOf(j));

Comment: Just so you know, this is very basic way to solve and mostly for beginners to understand. 
But ideal way is to use a right data structure to achieve those.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is too use [distinct()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) from stream API:

```
List<String> distinct = elements.stream()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```